# NoClassDefFoundError in Volley with mocked context

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito, android-volley

I'm getting this error when I try to test a class that uses Volley:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient
    at asee.giiis.unex.proyectoasee.CargaJson.NetworkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivity.loadClubs(NetworkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivity.java:66)
    at asee.giiis.unex.proyectoasee.CargaJson.NetworkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivityTest.loadClubs(NetworkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivityTest.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 31 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

This is the test class:

```
package asee.giiis.unex.proyectoasee.CargaJson;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.test.mock.MockContext;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import asee.giiis.unex.proyectoasee.room.BarItemDao;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer;

import asee.giiis.unex.proyectoasee.model.BarItem;

import static androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.RecordedRequest;



import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class NetworkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivityTest {
    private static MockWebServer mockWebServer;
    @Mock
    Context mockContext;
    private static SharedPreferences mockPrefs;
    private static String jsonPrueba="{\"head\":{\"vars\":[\"uri\",\"schema_url\",\"schema_email\",\"geo_long\",\"schema_telephone\",\"geo_lat\",\"om_capacidadPersonas\",\"rdfs_label\",\"schema_address_postalCode\",\"schema_address_addressCountry\",\"schema_address_addressLocality\",\"schema_address_streetAddress\"]},\"results\":{\"bindings\":[{\"uri\":{\"type\":\"uri\",\"value\":\"http://opendata.caceres.es/recurso/turismo/establecimientos/CafeBar/0-adarve\"},\"geo_lat\":{\"type\":\"typed-literal\",\"value\":\"39.474155\",\"datatype\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal\"},\"geo_long\":{\"type\":\"typed-literal\",\"value\":\"-6.372416\",\"datatype\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal\"},\"rdfs_label\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"Adarve\",\"xml:lang\":\"es\"},\"schema_email\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"cafeadarve@gmail.com\"},\"schema_telephone\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"+34 927244874\"},\"om_capacidadPersonas\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"30 pax\"},\"schema_address_postalCode\":{\"type\":\"typed-literal\",\"value\":\"10003\",\"datatype\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int\"},\"schema_address_streetAddress\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"Calle Maestro Sánchez Garrido, 4 \",\"xml:lang\":\"es\"},\"schema_address_addressCountry\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"ES\"},\"schema_address_addressLocality\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"Cáceres\",\"xml:lang\":\"es\"}},{\"uri\":{\"type\":\"uri\",\"value\":\"http://opendata.caceres.es/recurso/turismo/establecimientos/CafeBar/10-la-estancia\"},\"geo_lat\":{\"type\":\"typed-literal\",\"value\":\"39.471489\",\"datatype\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal\"},\"geo_long\":{\"type\":\"typed-literal\",\"value\":\"-6.376419\",\"datatype\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal\"},\"rdfs_label\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"La Estancia\",\"xml:lang\":\"es\"},\"schema_telephone\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"+34 927248064\"},\"om_capacidadPersonas\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"50 pax\"},\"schema_address_postalCode\":{\"type\":\"typed-literal\",\"value\":\"10003\",\"datatype\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int\"},\"schema_address_streetAddress\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"Plaza Mayor, 6 \",\"xml:lang\":\"es\"},\"schema_address_addressCountry\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"ES\"},\"schema_address_addressLocality\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"Cáceres\",\"xml:lang\":\"es\"}},{\"uri\":{\"type\":\"uri\",\"value\":\"http://opendata.caceres.es/recurso/turismo/establecimientos/CafeBar/1-al-andalus\"},\"geo_lat\":{\"type\":\"typed-literal\",\"value\":\"39.46308\",\"datatype\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal\"},\"geo_long\":{\"type\":\"typed-literal\",\"value\":\"-6.379171\",\"datatype\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal\"},\"rdfs_label\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"Al-Andalus\",\"xml:lang\":\"es\"},\"schema_address_postalCode\":{\"type\":\"typed-literal\",\"value\":\"10005\",\"datatype\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int\"},\"schema_address_streetAddress\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"Avenida Isabel de Moctezuma, 22\",\"xml:lang\":\"es\"},\"schema_address_addressCountry\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"ES\"},\"schema_address_addressLocality\":{\"type\":\"literal\",\"value\":\"Cáceres\",\"xml:lang\":\"es\"}}]}}";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void before(){
       // mockContext= getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
    }

    @Test
    public void init() {
        //creo que no se hace nada
    }

    @Test
    public void loadClubs() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {


        //we create a mock server, independent of the real server
        MockWebServer mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
        MockResponse mockResponse=new MockResponse();
        mockResponse.setResponseCode(200);
        mockResponse.setBody(jsonPrueba);

        mockWebServer.enqueue(mockResponse);
        System.out.println(mockWebServer.url("").toString());

        //pasando al atributo privado

        NetworkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivity networkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivity = new NetworkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivity(mockContext);

        final Field field= networkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivity.getClass().getDeclaredField("url");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(networkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivity,mockWebServer.url("").toString());

        Field fieldListBars= networkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivity.getClass().getDeclaredField("barItems");
        fieldListBars.setAccessible(true);

        networkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivity.loadClubs(mockContext);



        System.out.println("--");


        System.out.println(fieldListBars.get(networkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivity));        //con la carga de datos


        mockWebServer.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void parseJson() {
    }

    @Test
    public void getBarItems() {
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllBarsLoaded() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void cerrarConexionMock(){

    }
}
```

And this is the method I'm trying to test, it throws an exception when Volley tries to get a request in 'Volley.newRequestQueue(context);'

```
public void loadClubs(Context context) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        // prepare the Request
        JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, this.url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // display response
                        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                        try {
                            parseJson(response.toString());
                            saveBars();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );

        // add it to the RequestQueue
        queue.add(getRequest);


    }
```

I think this could fail because of the mocked context, but I don't know how to solve it.